# Is House Resolution 368 Permenant?

Tags: united-states, congress, procedure

US House Resolution 368 amended Clause 4 of standing rule XXII of House Procedures and was passed on September 30th, just before the government shutdown took effect. It prevented members other than the Majority Leader from bringing motions passed by the Senate before the House.

Is this a permanent rule change, or will this change expire now that the shutdown has ended?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the US House of Representatives rule itself?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-does-the-us-house-of-representatives-rule-itself)

Comment: My answer to this [question is the answer](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-does-the-us-house-of-representatives-rule-itself/2201#2201) you are looking for. It permanently alters the rules for amendments to H.J.Res. 59, but not in the general sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule change is permanent (I think) but narrow in scope. It only pertains to the budget bill.

Source:

```
...takes from the Speaker's table the joint resolution (H.J. Res. 59) making
 continuing appropriations for fiscal year 2014
```

and

```
...relating to House Joint Resolution 59 may be offered only by the Majority
 Leader or his designee.
```